# Semantic UI Modal only opens once inside segment

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

This works once, but not the second time.  As you can see, the code for the modal gets moved to the end of the `body` tag when it's opened the first time.

I need to list several items on a page, each with their own modal, so how can I get this to work?

https://jsfiddle.net/mw60egz9/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, modals are moved outside the dimmable area. You must set **detachable** setting to **false** to avoid it. Try this on your code:

```
$(".ui.button").click(function() {
    var $segment = $(this).parent(".ui.segment").find(".ui.modal");
    $segment.modal({
          detachable: false
    }).modal("show");
});
```

```js
$(".ui.button").click(function() {
 var $segment = $(this).parent(".ui.segment").find(".ui.modal");
 $segment.modal({
     detachable: false
    }).modal("show");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery/jquery-ui/master/external/jquery-2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ui segment">

  <button class="ui button">Show</button>
  
  <div class="ui modal">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="description">
        <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur, repudiandae, culpa unde saepe dicta numquam ipsum at iusto voluptatibus corrupti laborum qui expedita impedit iste enim facere voluptatum molestias libero?
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```